# Pandas recursively drop values from each row if outside a limit

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a dataset that has temperature values from multiple sensors in 5min intervals.

The requirement is to

- calculate the mean from all sensors in each interval
- if any values are > 3% from the mean (above or below) then

  - drop the highest value (ie furthest from the mean)
  - recalculate the mean
- repeat if any remaining values are higher than the recalculated mean

This is different to other answers I've found where the entire row is dropped - I just need to successively drop the highest outlier until all values are within 3%.

I've tried a range of approaches but I'm going in circles. Help!

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) that replicates your problem, including the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is loop until your condition is met (no more values >3% from mean).

```
import pandas as pd
values= {
       "col" :[90,85,80,70,95,100]
              }
index_labels=["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
df = pd.DataFrame(values,index=index_labels)

all_within_three_percent = False #set condition to false by default
while all_within_three_percent == False: #while condition is not met, while loop keeps looping
    mean = df.col.mean() #(re)calculate mean
    three_percent_deviation = mean*0.03 #(re)calculate current deviation threshold
    df['deviation'] = abs(df.col - mean) #determine individual row deviations (absolute, so both above and below mean)
    if sum(df['deviation'] > three_percent_deviation) > 0: #when there are deviation values above the threshold
        df = df.drop(df['deviation'].idxmax()) #delete the maximum value
    else:
        all_within_three_percent = True #otherwise, condition is met: we're done, loop should be stopped
df = df.drop('deviation', axis=1) #drop the helper column deviation
```

returns:

```
    col
E   95
F   100
```

Note that when the difference is the same, it will remove the first occurrence. After the first iteration (removing 70), the mean is 90, so both 80 and 100 have a difference of 10. It will remove 80, not 100.